# drawViewHierarchyInRect hangs when called with a timer

Tags: uiview, uikit, ios7

Supposed to have this method to create UIView snapshot

```
+ (UIImage *)screenshotWithView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0f);
    if( [view respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)] ) { // LP: iOS 7 only
        [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds
                   afterScreenUpdates:[view superview]?NO:YES];
    } else {
        [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    }
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

When executing this method in a time, let's say something like

```
runTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0f/30
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(sendScreen)
                                              userInfo:nil

                                       repeats:repeat];
```

the app becomes slower and slower. The UI does not freeze, and the snapshot is taked, but performances dramatically decreases.

That is exactly what Apple does not suggest here abuot the new UI methods for iOS7:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW217

When using the classic

```
 [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

everything works as expected, but of course we knew this already.

No success when trying the

```
- (UIView *)snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates
```

Comment: I have not seen performance improvements with drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: In fact I have seen it slower sometimes.